# I can't read in java returned array from plpgsql function

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, return, plpgsql

Postgres plpgsql function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usersList()
RETURNS TABLE(at varchar,name varchar,surname varchar)  AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM users;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And java code

```
result = Pstatement.executeQuery("Select usersList() ");
while(result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getString(("at")));
    System.out.println(result.getString(("name")));
    System.out.println(result.getString(("surname")));
}
```

Java error sql exception message :

```
Message: The column name at was not found in this ResultSet.
SQLState: 42703
ErrorCode: 0
```

How can i return all table columns from a function and then print them in java ?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM usersList()`.

Comment: Yep, `SELECT usersList()` treats `usersList()` as a field, and packs the output columns into a single value (of type `record`). `SELECT * FROM usersList()` treats `usersList()` as a table, and gives you the result you're expecting.

Comment: Its really works.Thnx you. Added as answer to vote it as the right one !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres plpgsql function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usersList()
RETURNS TABLE(at varchar,name varchar,surname varchar)  AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM users;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And java code

```
result = Pstatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usersList() ");
while(result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getString(("at")));
    System.out.println(result.getString(("name")));
    System.out.println(result.getString(("surname")));
}
```

Credits to RealSkeptic && Nick Barnes !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result.getMetaData().getColumnCount()` to see how many columns you retrieved and then you can call `result.getMetaData().getColumnName(x)` to check the name of the column (replace `x` with the number of column).

So technically you should be able to write your code block like so:

```
result = Pstatement.executeQuery("Select usersList() ");
String mesites[];
while(result.next()) {
    int columnCount = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("Found:"+columnCount+" columns.");
    for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++){
        System.out.println(result.getString(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)));
    }
}
```

Which should then print out any columns retrieved in that result set regardless of names (if any).

Comment: Found:1 columns.
(" at1",name1,surname1)
Found:1 columns.
(" 123456",george,gtest)
.
.
.